# zoom to an object without using the NumPad

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut

I zoom all the time for many situations, but most of the time the zoom goes to nowhere and I have to adjust all the time to get the right spot. I have tried <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> which works ok only sometimes.
I can press <kbd>NumPad</kbd> because I'm on my laptop, and I can't find a similar way.

What I need the best is to select an object from my scene list, then click for a zoom  that will bring me the right zoom for that object.
Is there a handy way to do this on a laptop?
Also what would be handy is a zoom to center, I could not find a laptop solution for this.

Comment: For those with the same problem: In version 2.79 (and possibly before): the zoom target is the mouse pointer location. Whether you use numpad +/- keys or the MMB, zoom or dolly is done around this point. If objects go out of view when zooming in, maybe this is because your mouse pointer is far from them and you are zooming to an empty area.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the menu item 3D view header *View* > *View Selected*, that is the same command as pressing <kbd>NumPad .</kbd>

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> will center the view depth over whatever the mouse hovering on.

<kbd>Home</kbd> will zoom and center the view so all objects are in view.

Possibly the best solution for you is in the *User Preferences* under the *Interface* tab then check the two boxes for *Auto Depth* and *Rotate Around Selection*. That will make the viewport rotate around whatever object(s) is selected.
[image: User Preferences]

Also in the user preferences under the *Input* tab you could try enabling the *Emulate NumPad* check box. That will make the regular 1-0 keys act like the NumPad.

Comment: yes i have the 1-0 keys done, but there is no "." involved there. the View > View Selected seems a good solution , i will make a hotkey for that , and i am good to go. this is exactly that i was searching for. and it works as expected.  i will try to see if the auto depth works for me. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Hold backtick (<kbd>**`**</kbd>) then select View Selected in the pie menu or press <kbd>**3**</kbd> or <kbd>**V**</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

You could also remap the key in input, search for "View selected" in input and remap it to for example . on you laptop.

Answer (score 2):

On my Dell M-4500 (French AZERTY keyboard), pressing the <*> key (bottom left of ENTER key, above the right SHIFT key) just toggles the 'zoom to object' back and forth and isolates the object.
Hope this helps.
Kind regards.